# Unable to find all issues through SonarQube WS API

Tags: mysql, sonarqube

**Goal**: Export all SonarQube issues for a project to JSON/CSV.

**Approach 1**: Mine the sonar mysql database

**Approach 2**: Use the SonarQube WS API

First I was motivated to go for approach-1, but having discussion with the SonarQube core developer community I got the impression not to touch the database at any situation.

Thus I proceed with approach-2 and developed scripts to get issues. However, later I found that through WS-API, I can get upto 10000 issues which does not meet my goal.

Now I am convinced that the approach-1 i.e., mining the database is best for me. When looking at the "***issues***" table in sonar db, I have the following question.

**Question**. What is the format/encoding of the "location" field and how can I decode it from python/java?

Comment: why do you need to export all SonarQube issues for a project? What is your use case?

Comment: I am using the data for research, so I need everything from the beginning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Extracting data from database is not recommended at all. Schema and content frequently changes. Each upgrade may break your SQL request. Moreover it contains binary data (issue location) which can't be parsed as-is.

The only way to get data is through web services. If api/issues/search faces a limitation that you consider as critical, then you should explain your functional need to the SonarQube google group.

Comment: I need the data for a single shot, thus future compatibility is not an issue for me. Could you kindly answer Q1, if you know.

I assume the open source part of SonarQube issues/search WS API does the "location" decoding already. Can you point me to this code?

Comment: It is protocol buffer. I can only give you the link to https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/blob/master/sonar-db/src/main/protobuf/db-issues.proto but then I can't support you for deeper understanding.